# Ubuntu 12.10 Module wl not found

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom

I was trying to install the b43 drivers, but I couldn't because the module wl was not found. I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I know this is not much information so ask me to enter any commands in the terminal if needed.

Comment: Well, you could start by explaining *how* you tried to install the drivers.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280. Either b43 OR wl is correct for your device and they are not interchangeable.